# Excel Vlookup range or if function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, merge, vlookup

I have been struggling to find a formula that works for the example below (see question mark!).  What i am trying to do is merge 2 datasets. The problem is that the common identifiers are not always exactly the same but quite similar nevertheless. I tried using the vlookup function making the last argument of the function (lookup range) true or using the number 2 instead (in an attempt to add 2 to the identifier, but the function returns me the value of the closest identifier (that is 7800).

1st dataset :

Identifier =>0000000161200103 price =>7787

Identifier =>0000000161200712 price =>7800

Identifier =>0000001961200803 price =>9000

2nd dataset  :

Identifier =>0000000161200103 price =>7787

Identifier =>0000000161200801 price => ????? returns either the closest (7800) or #N/A.

What i need to be returned is the value **9000**. Ideally, I need to be able to manipulate somehow the lookup value range that vlookup searches (upward or downward) or what to do next with the lookup value if there is no exact match.. maybe with an if function or iferror of isna...but i just cannot get there.

The functions i tried are the following:
=VLOOKUP($A2;A2:B4;1;TRUE) -> returns cell B3
=VLOOKUP($A2;A2:B4;1;1)  -> returns cell B3
=VLOOKUP($A2;A2:B4;1;2)  -> returns cell B3 
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2;A2:B4;1;1;FALSE)) = TRUE; VLOOKUP(($A2+2);A2:B4;1;FALSE); VLOOKUP($A2;A2:B4;1;FALSE))  -> returns #N/A

Any help deeply appreciated!

Comment: Try to format edit your post, it's barely readable as it is.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do.  You will have to be more detailed.  If it doesn't find a match, what do you want to do?  How do you determine what is the *best* match?

Comment: You 're right! I tried making the post more clear! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You are still not explaining the logic.  Why is 9000 being picked??  Is it because it is the last in that column?  Is it because it is the next row after the closest match?  Is it because you think it is the closest match?  Excel is going look at numeric lookups in numerical order and assume your column is sorted.  Once it finds a value that is higher than the lookup value, it will assume it went too far and go with the previous row as the best match.

Comment: 9000 is the value that i would like to be returned with a function of some type. The vlookup function returns me the value 7800 instead because the identifier 0000000161200801 is closest to 0000000161200712 rather than  0000001961200803 that i would like it to use..Yeah im sorry..i am doing my best to explain.

Comment: I get that, what I am asking is how do you decide that 9000 should be the value to return?  Should 9000 be returned every time there is no match??

Answer (score 2):

You can do a vlookup with the 4th arg as 0.  This will return an error if there is no match.  You can wrap that in an if statement and decide what to do from there.

```
if(vlookup("0011..",a1:a4,1,0),vlookup("0011..",a1:b4,2,0),..dosomethingelse..)
```